# Как можно обойти защиту от скачивания фотографии при помощи requests?

Tags: python, requests

Час добрый
Подскажите пожалуйста как при помощи requests можно вытащить изображение со следующей ссылки:

```
https://3125tiger.x.yupoo.com/42080879?uid=1
```

При помощи bs4 получил нужный пут до полной картинки, но сохранить ее не выходит т.к. если делать простой get запрос на эту ссылку, то срабатывает защита и скачивается следующее изображение:

```
https://prnt.sc/DNMOwMjV406m
```

Такая же картинка вылазит если зайти на ссылку для полной версии изображения БЕЗ посещения страницы с которой получаем пут к полной версии изображения. Однако если открыть первую ссылку в новой вкладке, то после обновления ссылки с полной картинкой - появится нужное изображение

ОТРЕДАКТИРОВАНО
Попробовал как посоветовали получить через сессию, если вычесть из кода элементы поиска необходимых элементов по div-ам при помощи bs4, то код был следующим:

```
headers = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36"
        }


s = requests.Session()

request = s.get(ссылка на главную, headers=headers)
request = s.get(ссылка на альбом, headers=headers)
request = s.get(https://3125tiger.x.yupoo.com/42080879?uid=1, headers=headers)
cookies_data = s.cookies  
request = s.get(ссылка на альбом, headers=headers, cookies=cookies_data)

Так же пробовал обновлять через:
s.cookies.update(cookies_data)
```

Comment: Выполнять запросы в сессии, чтоб куки передавались.

Comment: @RomanKonoval Сессия с передачей кукисов не помогла, только что проверил

Answer (score 0):

Открываем панель разработчика и видим, что в картинке прописан путь до самой картинки без элементов интерфейса. Выглядит это таким образом:

```
<img alt="" title="Width: 750px
Height: 891px
Frame: 1" class="viewer__img animate__startAnimate" data-src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH4QEYERgS1UcUEQAAABl0RVh0Q29tbWVudABDcmVhdGVkIHdpdGggR0lNUFeBDhcAAAAQSURBVAgdAQUA+v8AAAAAAAAFAAG6iRCKAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" src="//photo.yupoo.com/3125tiger/854c31a5/4e7bc587.jpeg">
```

Далее вам нужно просто выбрать данные из `src`, убрать `//` и получаем ссылку: [photo.yupoo.com/3125tiger/854c31a5/4e7bc587.jpeg](https://photo.yupoo.com/3125tiger/854c31a5/4e7bc587.jpeg)

Далее передаём её в `requests` и через него качаем

Comment: А вот и не выходит, писал же выше что если обращаться гет запросом без активной открытой вкладки, то с качается совершенно другое изображение. Даже если просто перейти на ссылку которую вы написали без посещения страницы от куда вы достали эту ссылку, то увидите что изображение изменилось на то, скрин которого я отправлял выше

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. За место того чтобы открывать ссылку в таком виде:

```
photo.yupoo.com/3125tiger/854c31a5/4e7bc587.jpeg
```

Заменил в ней photo на pic и все заработало

```
pic.yupoo.com/3125tiger/854c31a5/4e7bc587.jpeg
```